# Efficient way of populating pandas table, using data from the same table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please take a look at the table below, I will try to explain what is going on there.

```
         A               AVG(A)           COEF       A PREDICTION

1   7.711311e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
2   7.954800e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
3   7.936405e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
4   7.943156e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
5   8.058328e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
6   8.262795e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
7   8.571035e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
8   8.594560e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
9   8.633982e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
10  8.449065e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
11  8.471940e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
12  8.498411e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
13  8.938666e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
14  9.118592e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
15  9.148847e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
16  8.894800e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
17  8.981288e+06  8.480469e+06        1.020306           NaN
18  9.054566e+06  8.559484e+06        1.021430           NaN
19  9.126747e+06  8.628422e+06        1.016544           NaN
20  9.209076e+06  8.703285e+06        0.959278           NaN
21  9.229077e+06  8.778928e+06        0.977292           NaN
22  9.103907e+06  8.840432e+06        0.988755  9.019947e+06
```

- a) Column `A` is given and we are interested in predicting next A.
- b)
  `AVG(A)` is a rolling average of A (window = 17)
- c) `COEF` column is
  precalculated and helps us to predict A
- d) `A PREDICTION` column is calculated as follows:

`df['A PREDICTION'] = df['AVG(A)'] * df['COEF'].shift(5)`

I know that my `A PREDICTION` column is fairy accurate so I would like to continue my table for another 5 rows (since I have 5 more coefficients). In order to do that I would need to continue `A` column, but  I dont have more data there so I am going to use my predictions instead. I.e the next row should start as follows:

```
         A               AVG(A)           COEF       A PREDICTION

1   7.711311e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
2   7.954800e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
3   7.936405e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
4   7.943156e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
5   8.058328e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
6   8.262795e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
7   8.571035e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
8   8.594560e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
9   8.633982e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
10  8.449065e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
11  8.471940e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
12  8.498411e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
13  8.938666e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
14  9.118592e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
15  9.148847e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
16  8.894800e+06           NaN             NaN           NaN
17  8.981288e+06  8.480469e+06        1.020306           NaN
18  9.054566e+06  8.559484e+06        1.021430           NaN
19  9.126747e+06  8.628422e+06        1.016544           NaN
20  9.209076e+06  8.703285e+06        0.959278           NaN
21  9.229077e+06  8.778928e+06        0.977292           NaN
22  9.103907e+06  8.840432e+06        0.988755  9.019947e+06
23  9.019947e+06
```

After, I would calculate `AVG(A)` and multiply it by `1.021430` to get `A PREDICTION` on row 23, after I would use that `A PREDICTION` on row 24, calculate next `AVG(A)` and multiply it by `1.016544` and get my next `A PREDICTION` etc.

Is there an efficient way of doing something like this?

Comment: You need for loop then : -)

Comment: How would I use it in pandas df?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html